# Software for showing the meaning of the words on double click in ubuntu pdf viewer

Tags: 20.04, pdf, dictionary

I want to know if there is any possible way to fastly know the meaning of unknown words while reading through ubuntu's default pdf viewer. I will have to copy and google the word to know the meaning.

What if the pdf viewer prompts the meaning of the word on double click? That would be great! Is there any possible way to get that feature? Any software to install?
I don't want other pdf viewers which meet the requirement but don't have other features which ubuntu one has.

Comment: What do you mean by meaning of the word? Like a dictionary or some kind of translator?

Comment: I don't know for PDF, however [Foliate](https://johnfactotum.github.io/foliate/) has an inbuilt dictionary for Epubs.

Answer (score 4):

You can try Okular instead of the default PDF viewer (Evince). It has an option to google search for a word or a phrase. You can also configure the options,and enable search in Wikionary and the Merriam-Webstar dictionary.

[image: okular word select]
You can install it with

```
sudo apt install okular
```

Not exactly what you wanted, but this is the next best thing.

Comment: Solves the problem to some extent but yeah the next best thing! Other features in Okular are really good, overall better than the default one.

Comment: Yes, Okular supports creating various kinds of annotations, as well as filling forms to some extend.

Answer (score 0):

Open the PDF Document using LibreOffice Draw.

Then you can right click and see synonyms of whatever word you select.

[image: Image.]